# Windows 7: Notification area settings are lost on restart

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Tray Icon's Behavior occasionally reset Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/377696/why-does-my-tray-icons-behavior-occasionally-reset-windows-7)

Recently noticed that my icons settings in notification area are getting reset on system restart.

For example I specify Skype icon to always show icon and notification.
After I restart Windows - it's hidden again.
It's not just for one specific icon, it's for all of them.

Checking box "Always shows icons and notifications" works, and all icons appear, but this is not an option.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem! Hope somebody finds an answer! This similar question may be helpful but seems to be Outlook specific: http://superuser.com/q/377696/101146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by re-installing Windows 7.

Comment: there must be another way to fix such a minor issue, I will not reinstall my whole system for this..

Comment: That's the only way.